# Can't redirect Trace.WriteLine to Serilog using SerilogTraceListener

Tags: trace, serilog

In one of my project (.net core 3.1), I need a way to redirect System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine to Serilog file. I found the SerilogTraceListener package which seems to be the right candidate.

Unfortunately until now, I haven't been able to find a way to make it works.

To reproduce it,
1) Create a .net core console project
2) Add the following nuget package : Serilog, SerilogTraceListener, Serilog.Sink.Console, Serilog.Sink.File
3) Overwrite the Program class code by the following

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Works fine
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                       .WriteTo.Console()
                       .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
                       .CreateLogger();
        Log.Logger.Information("A string written using Logger.Information");

        // Trace is written in the console but not in the file
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new global::SerilogTraceListener.SerilogTraceListener());
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("A string written using Trace.WriteLine");
    }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*TL;DR;* You need to set the `MinimumLevel` to `Debug` or `Verbose` in order to see the `Trace.WriteLine` messages.

---

[SerilogTraceListener](https://github.com/serilog-trace-listener/SerilogTraceListener) maps `System.Diagnostic.TraceEventType` to `Serilog.LogEventLevel`, and when you call `Trace.WriteLine`, [it maps these events to the `Debug` log event level](https://github.com/serilog-trace-listener/SerilogTraceListener/blob/dev/src/SerilogTraceListener/LevelMapping.cs#L22).

That means Serilog's logger is receiving a message of type `LogEventLevel.Debug`.

The minimum level configured in Serilog by default is `Information`, which means `Debug` messages are being suppressed.

You have to configure the `MinimumEventLevel` to `Debug` (or `Verbose`) in order to see the `Trace.WriteLine` messages:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug() // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
    .CreateLogger();
```